# karma not finding any spec files after webpack build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am using the below karma.config.js to test an angular 5 application:
The output shows that the spec files are being built by webpack.
But they are not being executed.

**Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.014 secs / 0 secs)**

```
Built at: 2018-4-6 11:41:27
                                                Asset      Size                                                 Chunks             Chunk Names
wwwroot/ts/app/modules/party/ContactComponent.spec.ts  2.36 MiB  wwwroot/ts/app/modules/party/ContactComponent.spec.ts  [emitted]  wwwroot/ts/app/modules/party/ContactComponent.spec.ts
                            wwwroot/ts/sanity.spec.ts   841 KiB                              wwwroot/ts/sanity.spec.ts  [emitted]  wwwroot/ts/sanity.spec.ts
Entrypoint wwwroot/ts/app/modules/party/ContactComponent.spec.ts = wwwroot/ts/app/modules/party/ContactComponent.spec.ts
Entrypoint wwwroot/ts/sanity.spec.ts = wwwroot/ts/sanity.spec.ts
[./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js] 613 KiB {wwwroot/ts/sanity.spec.ts} {wwwroot/ts/app/modules/party/ContactComponent.spec.ts} [built] [2 warnings]
[./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js] 48.6 KiB {wwwroot/ts/sanity.spec.ts} {wwwroot/ts/app/modules/party/ContactComponent.spec.ts}
```

So it seems that all (of 2) spec files are being built, but they don't appear to loading into karma.

```
06 04 2018 11:41:28.195:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
06 04 2018 11:41:31.277:INFO [Chrome 65.0.3325 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket hJfXueGxaOTtJn4SAAAA with id 21418556    
Chrome 65.0.3325 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.014 secs / 0 secs)
```

for reference my `karma.config.js` is as follows.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: "",
        frameworks: ["jasmine"],
        plugins: [
            require("karma-jasmine"),
            require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
            require("karma-jasmine-html-reporter"),
            require("karma-spec-reporter"),
            require("karma-webpack")
        ],
        files: [
    "./base.spec.ts",
    "./wwwroot/**/*.spec.*"
        ],
        webpack: {
            mode: "development",
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.ts$/,
                        use: ["ts-loader"],
                        exclude: /(node_modules)/
                    },
                    {
                        test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                        use: [
                           { loader: "expose-loader", options: "jQuery" },
                           { loader: "expose-loader", options: "$" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            resolve:
                {
                    extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".json"],
                    alias: {
                        typeahead: "typeahead.js"
                    }
                },
        },
        preprocessors: {
            "./base.spec.ts": ["webpack"],
            "./wwwroot/**/*.spec.*": ["webpack"]
        },
        reporters: ["kjhtml", "spec"],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ["Chrome"],
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

Comment: no suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a link to your github repo?

Comment: sure, here is a repo that contains just the two tests, and the components needed to execute the tests https://github.com/jimmymain/angular-test.

`npm install`
`npm run test`

Comment: it would be nice to have a test that actually does something a little more than add 1 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the mime type in your karma config will make your tests run.

```
mime: {
  "text/x-typescript": ["ts"]
},
```

Comment: I get a different error, 

Chrome 65.0.3325 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: Cannot read property 'getComponentFromError' of null

Comment: This error occures, because you initialise and run TestBed.get in `ContactComponent.spec.ts` out if an `it` context. Wrap in into `it` and you will get an component relevant error.

Comment: I have made the change, and moved the initialisation and added `it`. (pushed the changes to the repo). I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hmm I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getComponentFromError' of null` which has something to do with `TestBed.get(ContactComponent)`. I could not find out, what's the problem, yet :/

Comment: me too, I have tried using TestBed.createComponent too, but it's always undefined. I don't mind if all the dependencies are null, I just need to get the basic component to instantiate for the test. I also fixed providers, and put the component into `declarations`

Comment: I pushed some more changes, which might get me closer, but there's still a null injector. there seem to be no simple tutorials on setting up these tests from scratch. all rely on angular-cli - which for historic reasons I am not using

Comment: I have some more changes, which end up with `Error: This test module uses the component ContactComponent which is using a "templateUrl" or "styleUrls", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.` Seems we are getting closer :)

Comment: As compileComponents returns a Promise, I think the compilation is done after the test runs.

Comment: Now just the template cannot be loaded.

Comment: Thanks - ya trying to resolve that now. I am not sure how to add a path to the testbed. I need to add wwwroot as a root golfer

Comment: I am giving you the points, thanks for the help. I might end up changing the templates to use webpack to load them dynamically, rather than specifying url(s) anyway. It seems more robust to me, and will save a network hit. If you can figure out how to get the urls to load that would be great, but I can now move on...

Comment: Hmm sorry I cant help you to the end. But I am glad, that I could help you.

Comment: got it all working scipper - thanks very much for the extended help.